# Правильно ли расставлены запятые.

Tags: пунктуация

Нужны ли запятые там, где стоят скобки:
Я , не зная() что делать, сел на стул.
Не зная()что делать, я сел на стул.

Comment: @Алена77, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Запятые нужны. Деепричастный оборот с подчинёнными словами "не зная, что делать" можно трактовать как видоизменение предложения "не знаю, что делать", где главная и придаточная части не подпадают под особые случаи без разделения запятой (например, под случай "не знаю что/зачем"):

http://orfogrammka.ru/пунктуация/запятая_между_главной_и_придаточной_частью/
(Справочник по русскому языку. Пунктуация. Д.Э. Розенталь//РАЗДЕЛ 10 Знаки препинания в сложноподчиненном предложении, § 33.4)